# Changing variable definition based on language choice?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am creating a weather app, and I am trying to change the variables I have defined based on the language selected by a user. I don't need a language translation service because I want to input static data.

```
  const dateBuilder = (d) => {
    /** ~ English
    let months = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];
    let days = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"];
    **/

    //Akan
    let months = ["Ɔpɛpɔn", "Ɔgyefoɔ", "Ɔbɛnem", "Oforisuo", "Kotonimma", "Ayɛwohomumɔ", "Kitawonsa", "Ɔsanaa", "Ɛbɔ", "Ahinime", "Obubuo", "Ɔpɛnimma"];
    let days = ["Kwasiada", "Jowada", "Benada", "Wukuada", "Yawóada", "Fiada", "Memeneda"];

    //Hausa 
    /**
    let months = ["Janairu", "Faburairu", "Maris", "Afirilu", "Mayu", "Yuni", "Yuli", "Agusta", "Satumba", "Oktoba", "Nuwamba", "Disamba"];
    let days = ["lahadi", "litinin", "Talata", "laraba", "Alhamis", "Jumma", "Asabar"];
    **/

    let day = days[d.getDay()];
    let date = d.getDate();
    let sup = "";
    let month = months[d.getMonth()];
    let year = d.getFullYear();
    
    if (date == 1 || date == 21 || date ==31)
      {
        sup = "st";
      }
        else if (date == 2 || date == 22)
      {
        sup = "nd";
      }
        else if (date == 3 || date == 23)
      {
        sup = "rd";
      }
        else
      {
        sup = "th";
      }


    return `${day} ${date} ${sup} ${month} ${year}`
  }
```

Comment: moment with locale support?  why do this from scratch?  https://momentjs.com/

Comment: I am still new to this programming environment. I have never used momentjs. Would you mind assisting me on how to go about it ?

Comment: I just checked momentjs out and the languages enlisted there doesn't have my local languages. That's Akan and Hausa

Comment: I think you can create your own locale for momentjs - https://momentjs.com/docs/#/customization/.